# How can I uninstall the BBC Player app?

Tags: ps4

Does anyone know of a way to uninstall BBC iPlayer from the PS4? I have tried holding triangle on the app, looking around the internet and I can't find anything, if anyone can help me that would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this page from the Netflix FAQ](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/2452):

> 1. Begin from the PS4 Home Screen. ...
> 2. Navigate to the TV & Video section and highlight Netflix.
> 3. Press the Options button on the PlayStation controller.
> 4. Select Delete.
> 5. Select OK.

Replace "Netflix" with "BBC Player" and you're good to go.

Alternatively, you could go to the Settings menu and go to System Storage, then find BBC Player in your list of apps and then use <kbd>Options</kbd> > Delete as above.

Comment: wont work. Every other video player app- eg Netflix will let you go to options that let you check for updates etc. For some reason bbc iplayer will not let you do any of this when you press the option button. I myself never watch iplayer but it won’t let me delete the thing. It was on my PS4 when I used to live with my parents but I don’t want it now.

Comment: i have the same issue, it's really annoying, i can install everything else but iPlayer